# Android exit daydream mode

Tags: android, android-intent

How can you programmatically exit the daydream mode?

It seems that daydream apps run as a modified service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/DreamService.html So would I need to implement task killing like functionality or can I use some intent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DreamService is a Service. So, you would stop the service like any other service, right? If it's a started service, you call stopSelf() or stopService() at the appropriate time - like when user touches the screen or presses a button to signal it's time to stop dreaming and wake up to reality. Am i missing something?

Comment: @harikris Yes, sorry I realize now my question is not clear. I don't own the Daydream service, so I need to end somebody else's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is owned by someone else i.e running with another Linux User ID (and hence on a difference Linux process), then i am afraid you can't terminate it unless you have root permission. Remember: Android system implements the `principle of least privilege`. So, you can't touch someone else's service component. Having said that, if you do have root permission, then you can kill any service if you could somehow figure out it's process id.

Sorry can't be of much help than this :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was thinking that maybe there is some clever solution with emulating user input? For example maybe if I emulate pressing the home button? I'll leave this question open for awhile to see if there are any other responses and then I'll accept yours :)

Comment: No problem. I think if the System owns this Service, it might allow other apps permission to manage it eg: by requesting permission in manifest file for system resources, etc.